# Form Components, to be used with both reactive and template driven form

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where i am trying to build out a component library and i am trying to find a solution for form components that will work with both reactive and template driven forms.

Currently i am injecting the formControlName and formGroup instance into the child component using `@Input()`, this works well for reactive forms. However, i cannot find a solution that will work for both reactive and template driven approaches, as `[(ngModel)]` creates its own formControlName which i can't (to the best of my knowledge) inject as the formControlName.

I would really like to be able to do the following.

Reactive Forms

```
<input-component
    formControlName="email"
    [formGroup]="form"
></input-component>
```

Template Driven Forms

```
<input-component
    [(ngModel)]="email"
    name="email"
></input-component>
```

Is this possible? Perhaps some way to look at the parent to derive these values instead of passing them down?

Thank you in advance.

**TS File** - as requested

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'ui-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() form_control_name: string;
    @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(

    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share input component ts code?

Comment: @Chellappanவ i have added the TS file.

Comment: Have you checked controlvalueaccessor? check this:https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` on your component.

You can read more abut it [here](https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf)

Comment: Thanks, this is a really clean solution.